# How to know which files to chmod in your website

Tags: php, javascript, html, web, terminal

If you have a website, and have different files doing different things, how should you chmod each file?

For example:

A CSS file which controls the layout of the HTML home page. How should I chmod that? 
A JS file with functions that give interactivity to the website. How should I chmod that? 
And a PHP file which communicates and changes the website's content from the server. How should I chmod that?

I understand how the chmod function works, but I don't understand what files you should chmod in what way. HELP! :D

Answer (score 0):

<s>You should give `750` to  PHP file.</s>

<s>For CSS and JS file `644` would be sufficient.</s>

All directories should have `755` permission and all files(php, js, html) should have `644` permission.

Comment: HTML would be 750 like a PHP file?

Comment: This is more of a general rule(applies most of the case), but might change from host to host.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the webserver (and all other relevant processes) can access and modify everything it needs to in order to function, you're fine.  It needs to be able to read all files it tries to access, and write into directories that it wants to upload files.

I use comprehensive ACLs in order to manage that logically on shared hardware.

```
$ man setfacl
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason not to (such as multiple users editing files, or you are using webserver-generated directory listings), I always use 711 permissions on all directories.  Apache is quite happy with this.

This stops local users from seeing what files you have in there (such as, say, notes, info or config files), and can offer some protection if other settings are misconfigured (+Indexes is turned on, say) or if you don't have the ability to change such settings.

Also, this setting follows the principle of setting minimum required access.  (Your mileage may vary on some web apps which need directories to be explicitly readable, but I haven't come across this.)